# Keep LinearLayout at the bottom of screen

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I know this question is asked a lot, because I was trying a lot of examples posted in here, but I just Can't make it work, this is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="500dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnTarjeta"
            android:background="@color/my_purple"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGp"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

One of the things that might be a "problem" is that I'm dynamically filling the radio buttons inside the radio group, so sometimes can be 4 radio buttons and in an other moment can be 1, I don't know if this affect any of what I'm trying to do.

And what I'm trying to do is keep the the first linear layer at the top, and the second linear layer at button.  What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, next time provide better description of what you exactly want. I'm not sure, but maybe you want this. Change your root `LinearLayout` `height` to `match_parent`, and remove first `LinearLayout` `android:gravity="bottom"`

[Screenshot of Android Studio Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0hjl.png)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do you have to put the height to your main container as `match_parent` with that you will expand the view as the height of the device screen, next I can't get the logic why your first child - LinearLayout has 0dp as `android:layout_height` but you should put it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and the last thing to do is to put `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to the second child LinearLayout.

Also I suggest to read for the difference of android:layout_gravity="" and android:gravity="" which are both LinearLayout properties.

Update:

1. Remove  android:gravity="center_horizontal" from main container it
   makes the children go to the center.
2. Remove  android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_weight="1" from
   first child why are you teling the first linear layout to go to the
   bottom?

Here is some clean code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnTarjeta"
            android:background="@color/my_purple"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGp"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `LinearLayout` `gravity` does not always work as expected, I suggest you make both internal `LinearLayout`s to have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and insert an empty `View` that will stretch vertically and fill all available space between the top and bottom content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_content"
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Button ... />
        <TextView ... />
        <RadioGroup .../>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <Button ... />
        <Button ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout_weight. 80 and 20 , it will work on all screens

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3F51B5"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="500dp"
android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTarjeta"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/my_purple"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/my_white" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:minWidth="25px" />
</LinearLayout>



  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of containers(Layouts).
If you want to put controls in a row but want to anchor it to the bottom you can use the mixture of `linear layout` and `relative like` this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".WebActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="backWeb"
            android:text="Back />
        <Button

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Home" />

        <Button
android:onClick="forwardWeb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Forward" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a linear view inside a relative layout:
[image]

Final result:

[image: screen shot]